# Formatting Dictionary into Columns

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to format this dictionary that the keys line up with the years. I am tried multiple formatting methods and I haven't been successful.

I have tried this:

```
def displayDegrees(degDict):
  print('Master degrees conferred in  fields. \n')
  print("Field of Study                    1981            2010")
  for k, v in degDict.items(): 
     print("{}       {}".format(k,v))
```

Any tips or hints would be much appreciated.

Comment: What data does your dictionary contain? Obviously you'll need three values for the three columns in your table, but it's not clear how those are contained in your dictionary.

Comment: It contains just counts of each degree - there are 2 values per each key

Comment: Check the built-in [`str.ljust()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust), [`str.rjust()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust) and [`str.center()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.center). They are also available to [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) as `<`, `>` and `^` options. Those are more than enough to produce the table you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what your dictionary looks like. But you can adapt the below method.

```
d = {'Business': [100000, 200000],
     'English': [50000, 150000],
     'Mathematics': [150000, 250000]}

cols = ['Field of Study', 1981, 2010]

print("{:>20} {:>10} {:>10}".format(*cols))

for k, v in d.items():
    print("{:>20} {:>10} {:>10}".format(k, *v))
```

Result:

```
      Field of Study       1981       2010
            Business     100000     200000
             English      50000     150000
         Mathematics     150000     250000
```

Comment: It's worth noting that you don't need to format every column the same way. The fields of study can be left justified with `<` and the numbers can be right justified with `>`. You can also add a comma to the format specifier to add thousands separators (e.g. `>10,`).

Answer (score 0):

```
dic = {"a":"b", "aaaaaaa":"bb"}

for key in dic:
    print ("{0}\t\t{1}".format(key, dic[key]))
```

gives the output

[image]